# How can I decode/print an IPV6 address in python

Tags: python, ip

I have an IPv6 address, and I would like to print it in a human readable format.

On an IPv4 address I did `socket.inet_ntoa(...)`, but on IPv6 I get

```
socket.error: packed IP wrong length for inet_ntoa
```

Comment: In addition to `inet_ntop`, you can also use `socket.getnameinfo()` with `socket.NI_NUMERICHOST` as the flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inet_ntop` (which works for both IPv4 and IPv6) instead of `inet_ntoa` (which is IPv4-only).

```
print(socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, '10::' )))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

> socket.inet_ntoa(packed_ip) Convert a 32-bit packed IPv4 address (a
>   string four characters in length) to its standard dotted-quad string
>   representation (for example, ‘123.45.67.89’). This is useful when
>   conversing with a program that uses the standard C library and needs
>   objects of type struct in_addr, which is the C type for the 32-bit
>   packed binary data this function takes as an argument.
>
> If the string passed to this function is not exactly 4 bytes in
>   length, socket.error will be raised. inet_ntoa() does not support
>   IPv6, and inet_ntop() should be used instead for IPv4/v6 dual stack
>   support.

You can use the library [IPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/) in order to take care of IPv4 and IPv6.

```
>>> print(IP('1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A'))
1080::8:800:200c:417a
```